# mysql - Difference between two times stored as text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two fields - **TimeStart** and **TimeFinish** - that are stored as `text` in an `sql database`. I am trying to calculate the difference in seconds between the two fields but all I get is NULL in the calculated **Difference** field. Any ideas?

```
SELECT TimeStart
    , TimeFinish
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND
                   , STR_TO_DATE(TimeFinish, '%h:%i')
                   , STR_TO_DATE(TimeStart, '%h:%i')) AS Difference
FROM table
```

Example of output

[image]

To try and figure it out I have just done the STR_TO_DATE using:

```
SELECT TimeStart
    , TimeFinish 
    , (STR_TO_DATE(TimeFinish, '%H:%i:%s')) AS Finish
    , (STR_TO_DATE(TimeStart, '%H:%i')) AS START 
FROM table
```

and got this:

[image]

so something is working.

Comment: Please also add some of the data rows (especially TimeFinish and TimeStart) so that people can see what the content of the fields is

Comment: Please don't store dates or times in  a database as text fields!  Store them as a `date`, `datetime`, or `timestamp`  type.

Comment: What do the stored values look like? You're using `%h`, which is twelve-hour time; you likely want `%H`. You don't have a seconds field in your `STR_TO_DATE`, either. `TIMESTAMPDIFF` expects a `DATE` or `DATETIME` value, and you're only providing a `TIME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue with your approach is that "%h" is hour in 12-hour notation, for 24-hour notation you need to use "%H":

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(TimeFinish, "%h"), STR_TO_DATE(TimeFinish, "%H") from table;
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE(TimeFinish, "%h") | STR_TO_DATE(TimeFinish, "%H") |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| NULL                          | 21:00:00                      |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Though, it on itself doesn't help, `TIME_DIFFERENCE` still returns `NULL`. To address that you can replace it with TIME_TO_SEC instead and compute their difference:

```
mysql> select TimeStart, TimeFinish, TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(TimeFinish, '%H:%i')) - TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(TimeStart, '%H:%i')) as Difference from moo;
+-----------+------------+------------+
| TimeStart | TimeFinish | Difference |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| 21:45     | 21:47      |        120 |
+-----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store your values as a TIME field, you can use the following.

```
SELECT TimeStart, TimeFinish,  
(TIME_TO_SEC(TimeFinish) - TIME_TO_SEC(TimeStart)) AS Difference 
FROM test
```

Comment: I was already working on a fiddle, so here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d1d2/1. **Watch out** for the case where the time goes from before midnight to past midnight. That will bite you :)